# Turning a script into a function

Tags: javascript, html, function

The following code is for a chatango chatbox and could be just placed into my html where I want the chatbox to appear.

```
<script id="cid0020000138099774487" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 350px;height: 800px;">{"handle":"mychatbox","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"000000","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"CCCCCC","e":"000000","g":"F6F6F4","h":"000000","j":"FFFFFF","k":"666666","l":"333333","m":"000000","n":"FFFFFF","q":"FFFF66","r":100,"s":1,"w":0,"showhdr":0,"surl":0}}</script>
```

What I would like to do is make it harder (I appreciate not impossible) for people to view the code with ease. I don't want a disable right click solution. What I am hoping for is to be able to place the above code into a .js file as a function and then in the html where I want the chatbox to appear call the function to use the code. Either that or an alternative solution that will work.

My reasons are that I am trying to make it harder for people to find out the chatango full page url. I'm happy to explain if someone wants to know why. Also the reason I would prefer it to be a function is that not only will the above code (I hope) not be visible in the html but also the replacement code will not have a src= pointing to which .js file in my header the code is in.

Is that possible and if so what would the .js file code be and also the html code to load it? Sorry I appreciate concepts but I am not a javascript programmer which is why I need to know what the code would be.

Comment: Please explain your reasoning. This sounds rather obscure. You can’t prevent people from reading client side JavaScript code – as long as the browser can read it, people will be able to decipher it as well. Just moving the code into another file doesn’t make it much harder.

Comment: sorry I thought I explained that I wanted to make it harder. If at least that part of the code is not "easily" viewable then my harder requirement will have been achieved. 
It does not matter what security anyone tries to introduce on a site (paid registration, IP Blocking etc. If a person banned from chat knows the full chatango URL they can bypass all security and get to the chatbox direct. The "handle":"mychatbox" in the code above gives them that. So I just want to make obtaining that harder.

Comment: Hiding (or at least making that bit of the code) is the missing part of the jigsaw that is preventing me from stopping a certain troll that has been plaguing my chatboxes for 2 years. So be my requirement obscure or not I would really appreciate a solution - as I said one that just makes it harder. I know it is not impossible to find but please as long as it is harder to find that will be good enough for me. I believe turning that bit into a function will achieve what I need.

Comment: Then just create the tag dynamically. See createElement, appendChild, dataset and innerText. If you still need help, I can expand into an answer tomorrow.

Comment: please see my original question- 
Sorry I appreciate concepts but I am not a javascript programmer which is why I need to know what the code would be.
I will look at what you have advised but I need to know for the code above what the .js and also what the html line for the function would be.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to have somebody write code for you. If you need a developer, you’ll need to pay him.

Comment: Answers to similar questions on Stackoverflow essentially say just remove the script tags but that would lose the data-cfasync, async src and style parameters. It is not like I was asking for a program to be written is it? Thanks for your help (not).

Comment: Well, I listed you all the methods the program could use above. What else could an answer now contain than a full solution? Your questions already says "I need to know what the code would be.". So you are requesting that somebody write code for you.

Comment: Yes on how to recode the script (the code of which I supplied) into a function. Yes I guess technically that is writing code - which in the majority of cases on StackOverflow very helpful people do in their answer instead of saying oh no you need to pay a developer to get the answer!

Comment: Then please just wait for somebody like that and stop bothering me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry you think I was bothering you by answering your commments - I expected a non complicated answer of what the script I supplied would be as a function and then the html for it being something like
   <script type="text/javascript">
   includechat();
   </script>